# Weird behavior (bug?) with RecyclerView And LinearLayoutManager with reverseLayout == true

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

When using RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and "reverseLayout" flag set to true, when notifying any item via `notifyItemChanged` it also calls `onBindViewHolder` for the first non-visible item. And it doesn't call `onViewRecycled` for that item afterwards whatsoever. So in case of a ViewHolder doing some kind of subscription in onBind it will never be released because onRecycle won't be called.

This actually looks like a bug in `LinearLayoutManager`. If you take a look at `fill` method in LinearLayoutManager, there is this code:

```
if (!layoutChunkResult.mIgnoreConsumed || layoutState.mScrapList != null || !state.isPreLayout()) {
    layoutState.mAvailable -= layoutChunkResult.mConsumed;
    // we keep a separate remaining space because mAvailable is important for recycling
    remainingSpace -= layoutChunkResult.mConsumed;
}
```

As far as I understand we iterate over child views until we fill all the needed space, in other words `layoutState.mAvailable` and `remainingSpace` which are both measured in pixels. And if you look further at what's going on in `layoutChunk` method you will see this piece of code:

```
// Consume the available space if the view is not removed OR changed
if (params.isItemRemoved() || params.isItemChanged()) {
    result.mIgnoreConsumed = true;
}
```

So the LLM will SKIP any item that has `FLAG_UPDATE` which, in my case, is the item I call `notifyItemChanged` on. By skipping I mean that the height of the item won't be subtracted from these two variables:

```
layoutState.mAvailable -= layoutChunkResult.mConsumed;
// we keep a separate remaining space because mAvailable is important for recycling
remainingSpace -= layoutChunkResult.mConsumed;
```

And this will make the loop iterate one more additional view. And since that view is not cached by the LLM (see `tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline` -> `getScrapOrHiddenOrCachedHolderForPosition`) (because if I'm not wrong it's outside of the screen bounds) it will be created anew. But in case of `reverseLayout` set to false (default LLM state) it won't iterate it because it will reach the end of the list first:

```
while ((layoutState.mInfinite || remainingSpace > 0) && layoutState.hasMore(state)) { ... }

Namely here:

boolean hasMore(RecyclerView.State state) {
    return mCurrentPosition >= 0 && mCurrentPosition < state.getItemCount();
}
```

In case of `reverseLayout` == false, we start iterating from the current position going in ascending order, i.e.:

```
    [ 0 ]   
 +--[ 1 ]--+
 |  [ 2 ]  |
 |  [ 3 ]  |
 |  [ 4 ]  |
 |  [ 5 ]  |
 +--[ 6 ]--+
```

Let's say we call `notifyItemChanged` on item with position 3. So the LLM will iterate over 1, 2, (skip 3), 4, 5 and 6. Since it skipped 3 there will be pixels left to fill in `layoutState.mAvailable` variable BUT because we are at the end of the loop it will stop right away.

Now let's see what happens when `reverseLayout` == true.

```
    [ 6 ]   
 +--[ 5 ]--+
 |  [ 4 ]  |
 |  [ 3 ]  |
 |  [ 2 ]  |
 |  [ 1 ]  |
 +--[ 0 ]--+
```

So again, we call `notifyItemChanged(3)`. LLM will start iterating in reversed order: 0, 1, 2, (skip 3), 4 and 5. Then since it skipped 3 there are still pixels to fill and we are NOT at the end of the list so it will iterate 6 as well.

What's the most strange thing is that in this code example it is only reproducible on the first long tap, afterwards first off-screen view's `onBind` won't get called. But in the project where this thing was discovered it is 100% reproducible every time you call `notifyItemChanged` on a view.

Here is minimal reproducible example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val id = AtomicLong(0)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val images = (0..6).map {
            return@map ImageItem(
                "https://i.imgur.com/BBcy6Wc.jpg",
                id.getAndIncrement()
            )
        }

        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true)
        recycler.adapter = Adapter(images).apply { setHasStableIds(true) }
        recycler.setRecyclerListener { viewHolder ->
            if (viewHolder is Adapter.MyViewHolder) {
                viewHolder.onRecycle()
            }
        }
        recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    data class ImageItem(val url: String, val id: Long)

    class Adapter(
        private val items: List<ImageItem>
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>(), OnRecyclerItemClick {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            println("TTTAAA onCreateViewHolder")

            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.my_view_holder, parent, false)

            return MyViewHolder(view, this)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder as MyViewHolder
            holder.onBind(items[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return items[position].id
        }

        override fun onLongClick(position: Int) {
            println("TTTAAA onLongClick($position)")
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }

        class MyViewHolder(
            private val view: View,
            private val callback: OnRecyclerItemClick
        ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            private val imageView: AppCompatImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_image)

            fun onBind(imageItem: ImageItem) {
                println("TTTAAA onBind $layoutPosition")

                imageView.setOnLongClickListener {
                    callback.onLongClick(layoutPosition)
                    return@setOnLongClickListener true
                }

                Glide.with(imageView.context)
                    .load(imageItem.url)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView)
            }

            fun onRecycle() {
                println("TTTAAA onRecycle $layoutPosition")
                imageView.setOnClickListener(null)

                Glide.with(imageView.context)
                    .clear(imageView)
            }

        }
    }
}

interface OnRecyclerItemClick {
    fun onLongClick(position: Int)
}
```

And here is the log:

```
onLongClick(0)
onCreateViewHolder
onBind 3
onCreateViewHolder
onBind 0
onRecycle 0
onLongClick(0)
onBind 0
onRecycle 0
onLongClick(0)
onBind 0
onRecycle 0
```

I'm longtapping the view with position 0 and an additional view with position 3 (which is off-screen) gets binded as well.